# How to update UITableViewCell.TextLabel.Text outside of the TableViewSource?

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have two view. First screen displays the list of cloud service page and the second screen displays accounts corresponding to the cloud service. In Cloud Service page , each row displays the list of cloud service like GoogleDrive, Box and etc. Navigating from first page to second page (eg. Google Drive) using UITableView Detail Closure button's AccessorButtonTapped  override method.

```
public override void AccessoryButtonTapped(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row == 0)
        {                
            GoogleDriveViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("GoogleDriveViewController") as GoogleDriveViewController;
            navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
        }
        else if(indexPath.Row == 1)
        {
            DropBoxViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DropBoxViewController") as DropBoxViewController;
            navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
        }
        else if(indexPath.Row==2)
        {
            BoxViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("BoxViewController") as BoxViewController;
            navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);                
        }
    }
```

In GoogleDrive page, it displays the list of google accounts . I have selected  one account and need to display the selected account in to first cloud service page GoogleDrive row label Text.

How to achieve this in UITableView?

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea but I do not recommend it.
You should see MvvmCross's NavigationService

```
public delegate void CompleteEventHandler(string username);

public class GoogleDriveViewController {
     ...

    public event CompleteEventHandler OnComplete;

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        OnComplete?.Invoke(username);
    } 
}

public override void AccessoryButtonTapped(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Row == 0)
    {                
        GoogleDriveViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("GoogleDriveViewController") as GoogleDriveViewController;

        vc.OnComplete += username =>{ theGoogleDriveCell.Label.Text = "GoogleDrive" + username  }; 
        or
        var index = indexPath;
        vc.OnComplete += username =>{ tableView.CellAt(index).Label.Text = "GoogleDrive" + username  };  

        navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
    }
    else if(indexPath.Row == 1)
    {
        DropBoxViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DropBoxViewController") as DropBoxViewController;
        navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
    }
    else if(indexPath.Row==2)
    {
        BoxViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("BoxViewController") as BoxViewController;
        navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You . I will check Navigation Service.